# native exception thrown from managed code skips native handler c++/cli

Tags: exception, c++-cli

I have some native C++ code (`native`) that calls a managed C++ function (`managed`) (in the same program) through a function pointer (`managed_ptr`) which is set earlier in the program. Similar to this:

Native function:

```
void(*managed_ptr)();
void native()
{
  try
  {
    managed_ptr();
  }
  catch (my_exception e)
  {
    // Handle exception
  }
}
```

Managed function:

```
void managed()
{
  // Code
  if(x)
    throw my_exception();
}
```

Exception type (native):

```
class my_exception final : public exception
{
public:
  my_exception() : exception("Error!") {}
}
```

When `managed` throws the native exception `my_exception`, however, it skips past the native exception try/catch and crashes the program with a `SEHException`. Why is this and how do I make it use a native handler for a native exception?

Thanks in advance,

MagikM18

**EDIT**

I tried creating a native function called `throwNative` so that the error would be thrown in native code, and calling that from managed code with the exception object, but that didn't work either.

throwNative:

```
template<typename _Ex> void throwNative(_Ex e)
{
  throw e;
}
```

Managed code:

```
// ...
throwNative(my_exception());
// ...
```

Comment: It is a simple rule, a managed try/catch can catch both a managed and an unmanaged exception.  A native try/catch doesn't know beans about managed exceptions, and how could it.  That requires the non-standard __try/__except keywords.

Comment: @HansPassant I understand that part but my_exception is native (I even used `#pragma unmanaged` to be sure) and it derives from the native exception class... so why shouldn't it be caught by a standard c++ try/catch?